# How to calculate the run time of a nested loop theoretically?

Tags: c++, for-loop, nested, runtime

I have a nested for loop in c++:

```
for(i=0;i<10000000;i++)
{
for(j=0;j<999999;j++)
    {
        //execute something
    }
}
```

I want to know:

- the number of hours this code will take to finish running.
- Will using a machine with more RAM and cores improve the run-time?
- How does my choice of language (MATLAB, Python, C/C++) will affect the run-time?

Comment: The most simple way is measure the time.

Comment: `How can I calculate its run time?` Just google it.

Comment: Short answer: no. Long answer: maybe.

Comment: I know the big-O notation. I just want to know how many statements get executed every second and will using a system with more RAM and cores improve it? @DimChtz

Comment: Depends on your //something. Some //somethings can be parallelized and benefit from multiple cores, some can't. RAM will only affect speed, if you deal with //something with sizeof() that is comparable to your total RAM size.

Answer (score 2):

if you are just asking for measuring the time you could use

```
#include <ctime>

int start_s=clock();
    // code
int stop_s=clock();
cout << "time (in milis): " << (stop_s-start_s)/double(CLOCKS_PER_SEC)*1000;
```

but if you wonder if this runtime would be better if got more ram or more cpu cores here is what you need :

short answer : it depends on "//execute something" block

long answer :
it doesn't depend directly on what the loop boundaries are, it just depend on what you do inside the nested loop 
here are a few double loop examples to demonstrate this

## if you are dealing with formulas then using a higher cpu frequency would be better

note that number of cores have nothing to do with running time as the code is not parallelized by default

```
sum = 0;
for(i=0;i<10000000;i++)
    for(j=0;j<999999;j++)
        sum+=1;
```

## if you are dealing with arrays then your RAM can make use of [spatial/temporal locality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference#Spatial_and_temporal_locality_usage) but the portion of your array saved in memory is limited by other parameters so bigger RAM wouldn't do much but using a higher RAM frequency would be better

```
int arr[10000000][999999];
arr[0][0] = 0;
for(i=1;i<10000000;i++)
    for(j=1;j<999999;j++)
        arr[i][j]=arr[i-1][j-1];
```

## if you are dealing with disk/buffer operation then neither your RAM or cpu can optimize it more than some level -hardware is the bottleneck-

```
    for(i=0;i<10000000;i++)
        for(j=0;j<999999;j++)
            cout << "yes";

    ofstream file;
    file.open ("out.txt");
    for(i=0;i<10000000;i++)
        for(j=0;j<999999;j++)
            file << "Writing to the file.\n";
```

Comment: Thank-you. This is really helpful :)